# Fetch OSM data, convert to vector file and load in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, openstreetmap, overpass-api, quickosm

I am writing a QGIS plugin in which one of the tasks is to fetch data (nodes, ways and relations) from open street map and display it on the plugin as a .shp file. Right now it returns the number of nodes and not the actual data.

My code snippet is as follows:

```
import overpy

class GetData():
    def __init__(self, p1, p2, console):
        print('getData Module Accessed')
        self.console = console

        api = overpy.Overpass()
        result = api.query('node({}, {}, {}, {}); out;'.format(p1.y(),p1.x(),p2.y(),p2.x()))
        nodes = len(result.nodes)

        consoleNodes = 'OSM Node:'+'<span style=\" color:#ff0000;\">'+'{}'.format(nodes)+'</span'
        self.console.append(consoleNodes)
```

`self.console` just shows the output.

Comment: QuickOSM already provides a large part of what you're trying to do, namely fetching data from Overpass API and import it in QGIS. I'd suggest to check out how their code.

Comment: And QuickOSM provides a Processing algorithm, so you can call it from Python already.

Comment: I think you should try your query in overpass turbo before. It's normal that you get the number of nodes because you `nodes = len(result.nodes)` returns the number of nodes. You should look `result.node` if you want your real nodes. 
Note that you can do that without any Python or just a few by using already existing QGIS Processing algorithm. Do you want an example?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I'm trying to figure out QuickOSM's code.Yes, your're right, 'result.nodes' prints out all the node ids alone with the coordinates which I am able to achieve. I'm trying to display the .osm data in the plugin like a .shp file layer in QGIS. Also an example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to your comments I have finally figured it out. The following code fetches and loads OSM building data in the canvas extent.

```
import processing
extent = iface.mapCanvas().extent()

## run a query in Overpass API and generate a download URL ##
results = processing.run("quickosm:buildqueryextent", 
                        {"KEY":"building", 
                         "VALUE":"yes", 
                         "EXTENT":extent})

## use the download Url to download the .osm file ##                     
osm = processing.run("native:filedownloader", 
                        {'URL':results['OUTPUT_URL'], 
                         'OUTPUT':'memory:'})

## extract multipolygons from the .osm file ##                     
shp = processing.run('quickosm:openosmfile', 
                        {"FILE":osm["OUTPUT"]})
    
## save the multipolygons vector file in a variable ##                
buildingLyr = shp['OUTPUT_MULTIPOLYGONS']

## add the layer to the project instance ##
QgsProject().instance().addMapLayer(buildingLyr)
```

for points and lines you can substitute `shp['OUTPUT_MULTIPOLYGONS']` to `shp['OUTPUT_POINTS']` and `shp['OUTPUT_LINES']` respectively

[QuickOSM Processing](https://docs.3liz.org/QuickOSM/processing/#parameters_5)